# Sustituir espacios por un caracter en un string C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, string, replace

Estoy intentando hacer un menú que almacene diferentes cosas y una de ellas es el nombre completo y quiero que cuando ingrese el nombre los espacios entre cada nombre y apellido sea cambiado por un "_".

Esto es lo que tengo, ignoren el bool de modificación ya que no hace nada por el momento lo que me interese es saber porque el "replace" no me funciona correctamente ya que al escribir el nombre es cambiado completamente por ese carácter.

PD: esta en la línea 68

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Datos
{

    string usuario;
    string canal;
    string nombre;
    char clasi[50];//clasificacion de canal
    string video; //videojuego que stremea el usuario
    char genv[50]; //clasificacion del videojuego

};

struct Datos u[100];

int i, j, z;
int opc; //opcion del menu
int opc2; //opcion de la clasificacion
int opc3;
int opc4; //opcion de genero videojuego
string bus1; //busqueda para modificar el usuario

int menu()
{
    int x;
    system("cls");
    cout << "<<-----Binevenido----->>" << endl << endl;
    cout << "1.- Agregar usuario" << endl;
    cout << "2.- Ver listas de usuario" << endl;
    cout << "3.- Modificar usuario" << endl;
    cout << "4.-Eliminar usuario" << endl;
    cout << "5.- Salir" << endl;
    cout << "¿Que desea hacer? ";
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}



void agregar(ofstream &es)
{
    int z;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    system("cls");
    


            cout << "\nIntroduzca su nombre de usuario: ";
            cin.ignore(); getline(cin, u[i].usuario);
            system("cls");
            remove_if(u[i].usuario.begin(), u[i].usuario.end(), ::isspace);
            
            cout << "\nIntroduzca su nombre: "; getline(cin, u[i].nombre);
            system("cls");
            u[i].nombre.replace(u[i].nombre.begin(), u[i].nombre.end(),' ', '_');
            
            cout << "\nIntroduzca el nombre de su canal: ";
            getline(cin, u[i].canal);
            system("cls");
            
            

            cout << "\nIngrese el Videojuego a emitir: " ;
            getline(cin, u[i].video);
            
            do
            {
                cout << "\nGeneros de videojuegos: ";
                cout << "\n1.- Shooter";
                cout << "\n2.- Aventura";
                cout << "\n3.- Deporte";
                cout << "\n4.- Terror";
                cout << "\n5.- Estrategia";
                cout << "\n6.- RolPlay";
                cout << "\n7.- Accion";
                cout << "\nSeleccione el genero del videojuego: "; cin >> opc4;
                system("cls");
                switch (opc4)
                {
                case 1:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].genv, "Shooter");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].genv, "Aventura");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].genv, "Deporte");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].genv, "Terror");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].genv, "Estrategia");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].genv, "RolPlay");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].genv, "Accion");
                    break;
                }
            } while (opc4 != 1 && opc4 != 2 && opc4 != 3 && opc4 != 4 && opc4 != 5 && opc4 != 6 && opc4 != 7);
            system("cls");

            
            
            do {
                cout << "\nClasificaciones de canal: ";
                cout << "\n1.- Todo Publico(TD)";
                cout << "\n2.- +18";
                cout << "\n3.- Para menores de edad(N)";
                cout << "\nSeleccione la clasificacion de su canal: "; cin >> opc2;
                system("cls");
                switch (opc2)
                {
                case 1:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].clasi, "TD");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].clasi, "+18");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    strcpy_s(u[i].clasi, "N");
                    break;
            
                }
            } while (opc2 != 1 && opc2 != 2 && opc2!=3);

            system("cls");


            cout << u[i].usuario << endl;
            cout << u[i].nombre << endl;
            cout << u[i].canal << endl;
            cout << u[i].clasi << endl;
            cout << u[i].video << endl;
            cout << u[i].genv << endl;
            system("pause");
            
            es.open("usuarios.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
            es <<i<<" "<< u[i].usuario << " " << u[i].nombre << " " << u[i].canal << " " << u[i].clasi << " " << u[i].video << " " << u[i].genv << "\n";
            i++;
            es.close();


    
}

int main()
{
    ofstream escritura;
    int sel;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        sel = menu();
        switch (sel)
        {
        case 1:
            agregar(escritura);
            break;
        }
    } while (sel != 5);
    return 0;
}


bool modificacion()
{
    
    int j = 0;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Introduzca el usuario a modificar: ";
    cin.ignore(); getline(cin, bus1);
    for (j = 0; j < 101; j++)
    {
        if (j)
        {

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual seria la linea 68?

Comment: Si tienes un problema con una sola instrucción en una sola línea del programa, **por favor** no compartas 195 líneas de código, eso es sólo ruido.

Por otro lado, observarás que StackOverflow muestra el código sin numerar las líneas, si nos dices que hay que revisar la línea 68 deberemos contar las líneas para averiguar cuál es la sexagésimo octava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando [`std::string::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) (una función miembro de `std::string`) y deberías estar usando [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) (una función de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm)).

Creo que estás llamando a la sexta sobrecarga:

```
basic_string& replace( const_iterator first, const_iterator last, size_type count2, CharT ch );
```

Que reemplaza `count2` caracteres por el caracter `ch`, el espacio (`' '`) tiene un valor de 32 por lo que si tu texto es más corto de 32 caracteres reemplazará todos los caracteres por `ch`. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de lo que realmente estás buscando:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s{"En un lugar de La Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme"};
    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ', '_');
    std::cout << s << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior genera la siguiente [salida](https://tio.run/##fY6xCgIxDIZn@xRBhyqc4qyHm5u@gSCxF2qhl55pO8jhs589VHRy@ZN8yf8T03VL45HtMMwcG58bgtqFmISw3akvK8Sx/SXobRCXruVMOU7QouP5QvVqElOz2bwMEPvpniEz@GxRoBgPCEdkc8VqnEy@B@DQXoRKgVt2JAHQBGlQWpo@tu88E3KCuoY4ij6x/iyEOo@G5nF1ITu@UEFcETdjo0EXOevFvxShlIVhvVWPYXgC):

> ```
> En un lugar de La Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme
> En_un_lugar_de_La_Mancha,_de_cuyo_nombre_no_quiero_acordarme
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Para reemplazar todas las string dentro de una string, puedes usar una función como esta:

```
void replaceAll(string& str, const string& sub, const string& rep) {
    int pos = 0;
    do {
        pos = str.find(sub, pos+1);
        if (pos != -1) 
            str.replace(pos, sub.length(), rep);

    } while(pos!=-1);
}
```